# Add className after added a new fullcalendar event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

Hello im using FullCalendar, after the calendar is completely loaded i add more events using 'addEventSource' with an url

```
calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', url)
```

And this works fine, but i want to add a custom class to these events, i don't know exactly how. i've tried modifying the events but my function apparently executes before the addEventSource one... So, what can i do? I read here that I should add the class from backend, but i can't edit the endpoint where i bring all the information of the calendar.

So, does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/

> This hook allows you to receive arbitrary event data from a JSON feed or any other Event Source and transform it into the type of data FullCalendar accepts. This let's you easily accept alternative data formats without having to write a completely custom events function.
>
> This function is called once per received event. eventData is the event data that has been receieved. The function must return a new object in the Event Object format.